# Why does "Magento Commerce" appear in place of my logo when I try to change it?

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, image

I've created a new logo for the index page of my Magento Commerce 1.8.1 installation and after I refresh the page, the logo doesn't show up.

Instead, there is a link to the index page with the title "Magento Commerce".

Why does this happen?

Comment: Turn on template hints and dig into the templates.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding out that the directory the image needed to be in was:

```
/skin/frontend/base/default/images
```

And the `Logo Image Src` had to be changed to `/images/logo.png`

---

**EDIT**

This path may be specific to the package I've installed into Magento called "Anybooking" but I'm not familiar enough with Magento to make that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration on System->Configuration->Design->Header there you put the path to your image and the alt you want it to show, the path is relative to your package name configured in the System->Configuration->Design->Theme and it's like this magento/skin/frontend/default/your_package/images/logo.jpg

With these you change it for every page of your Magento Store.

Comment: I have the path to the image setup like you have suggested, but it still only shows the "Alt" text - that's the only thing that is changing.  Is there a height and/or width requirement? Or a change to the CSS?

Comment: Try move the logo image to magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo.jpg